# Error in code Regex

Tags: scala

I am trying to find only the word contains 3 letters(e is below example) in the word
need to find using regex.

```
val inputString = """edepak,suman,employdee,eeeee,eme,ev"""
```

and i have written the below code.

```
val numberPatteren = "([a-z]*e){3,}".r
```

but i am getting the below output which is not as expected.

```
employdee,eeeee
```

but the output should be only -- employdee

can you please help me on this.

Comment: This question is very unclear. What does: "only the word contains 3 letters". "employdee" contains 7 (or 9).

Comment: i mean in "employdee" is having 3 e's so it should display only those words which are having 3 e's

Comment: I suspect regex is the wrong tool for the job, this is quite cleanly written as `.filter(_ == 'e').length == 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that simply by doing the following

```
scala> inputString.split(",").filter(word => word.count(_ == 'e') == 3).mkString(",")
//res16: String = employdee
```

If you want to use regex, you can do as below

```
scala> val numberPatteren = "[a-df-zA-DF-Z0-9]".r
//numberPatteren: scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-df-zA-DF-Z0-9]

scala> inputString.split(",").filter(numberPatteren.replaceAllIn(_, "").length == 3).mkString(",")
//res0: String = employdee
```